# Django RedirectFallbackMiddleware does not Work

Tags: django

We currently have a site running Django 1.7 with RedirectFallbackMiddleware but its not working on production. Local development machines are redirecting Ok. I've double-checked configs and everything but it looks like something related to the environment rather than Django itself.

My Middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
)
```

I'm using apache, i'm behind a proxy server, my response header is this

```
Cache-Control:max-age=86400
Connection:close
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:8685
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 24 Feb 2015 13:28:05 GMT
Expires:Wed, 25 Feb 2015 13:29:33 GMT
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

It looks like some caching issue... Although there's this nasty cache-control, i'm getting 404 statuscode and my default 404 template.

I'm clueless, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have another site running under the same proxy server without UpdateCacheMiddleware/FetchFromCacheMiddleware with the same problem

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue now, 4 years on

Comment: No, I remember giving up using Django with apache ~ 4 years ago. I believe this is not Django related, must be something in the stack. This particular server had Cpanel and other stuff installed.

Comment: Can you show your Apache configuration as well as your redirects list?

Answer (score 0):

We managed to fix this issue.

In our case this was due the handler404 in our view.py. 
We had a redirect in there which interfered which I didn't realise.

```
def handler404(request, exception):

    (...)
    if page != None:
       return redirect(page.get_absolute_url())
```

This is not standard, but was done by a dev.